# CSS Attribute Selcetor - Which one is faster?

Tags: css, performance, css-selectors

Which one is preferred in terms of performance?

```
a[href*="op.ExtSite.com/p"]

a[href*="shop.ExtSite.com/page"]

a[href^="http://shop.ExtSite.com/page"]

a[href^="http://shop.ExtSite.com/page"][href$=".html"]
```

**Update**

The last selector should have been written as follow:

```
a[href^="http://shop.E"][href$=".html"]
```

Also, regarding this multiple selector, I would like to know which condition is checked first, the left one or the right one?

Comment: Please don't spend time worrying about the tiny performance differences between different CSS selectors. If you really want to work on your site's performance, use a profiler and find the places where your own code is slow. Worrying about performance of indiviual CSS Selector is the job of the browser makers, not site designers.

Comment: @Spudley: I would be glad to know more about "profiling."

Comment: For front-end code on the browser, modern browsers have profiling tools built into them; see the dev tools option (press F12 in most browsers). Also try the [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) tool. If you've written server-side code, that should also be profiled, but the tool to use will vary according to the language you've written the code in. For most sites, the real performance bottlenecks will be on the server-side, usually with stuff like complex DB queries that are slow. Perfomance tuning is all about optimising the big things first.

Comment: Also, re spending time trying to fix the small things: This is commonly referred to as "Premature Optimisation". If you google that phrase, you'll get plenty more info about why it's considered a bad thing. Here's one good link: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: "Profiling" in general is the word used for measuring the performance of your code to find the places where it is slow. You can then use that information to help you decide what would be the most effective use of your time to spend trying to speed it up. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: @Spudley: I cannot vote up for the time being. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is either this one

```
a[href^="http://shop.ExtSite.com/page"]
```

or

```
a[href^="http://shop.ExtSite.com/page"][href$=".html"]
```

as it starts looking from the first of the string so all links that does not have `h` in the beginning will be avoided.

**UPDATE**
if you need to check on the full pattern then go with the one I mentioned below :

```
a[href^="http://shop.ExtSite.com/page.html"]
```

Comment: The last one cannot possibly be the fastest as it includes an extra check.

Comment: Please see my update. Also, the links that I want to match are like `http://shop.ExtSite.com/page/.../something.html`